# como adaptar el codigo de una tabla a un catalogo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

me ocupa lo siguiente:

Me estoy copiando de un codigo de un carrito en una tienda, la copia la estoy haciendo del siguiente codigo que tal cual como esta funciona de forma perfecta, pero que no es para nada atractivo de forma visual ni tampoco es responsive:

**php**

```
<?php
// connect to database
include 'config/database.php';
 
// page headers
$page_title="Lista de productos";
include 'head.php';
 
// to prevent undefined index notice
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$product_id = isset($_GET['product_id']) ? $_GET['product_id'] : "1";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "1";
 
// show message
if($action=='added'){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> ¡agregado a tu carrito!";
    echo "</div>";
}
 
else if($action=='failed'){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> No se pudo agregar a su carrito!";
    echo "</div>";
}
 
// select products from database
$query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, ci.quantity 
        FROM products p 
            LEFT JOIN cart_items ci
                ON p.id = ci.product_id 
        ORDER BY p.name";
 
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();
 
// count number of products returned
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
 
if($num>0){
     
    //start table
    echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
     
        // our table heading
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Nombre del producto</th>";
            echo "<th>Precio (USD)</th>";
            echo "<th style='width:5em;'>Cantidad</th>";
            echo "<th>Acciones</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
         
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
             
            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
                    echo "<div class='product-name'>{$name}</div>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>&#36;" . number_format($price, 2, '.' , ',') . "</td>";
                if(isset($quantity)){
                    echo "<td>";
                             echo "<input type='text' name='quantity' value='{$quantity}' disabled class='form-control' />";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo "<button class='btn btn-success' disabled>";
                            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Agregado!";
                        echo "</button>";
                    echo "</td>";             
                }else{
                    echo "<td>";
                             echo "<input type='number' name='quantity' value='1' class='form-control' />";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo "<button class='btn btn-primary add-to-cart'>";
                            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Añadir a la cesta";
                        echo "</button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
         
    echo "</table>";
}
 
// tell the user if there's no products in the database
else{
    echo "No hay productos encontrados.";
}
 
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

**javascript**

```
 </div>
    <!-- /container -->
 
<!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="libs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/js/holder.js"></script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        window.location.href = "agregar.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
    });
     
    $('.update-quantity').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        window.location.href = "actualizar.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
    });
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**El codigo lo he intentado modificar de la siguiente manera:**

```
// select products from database
$query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, p.imagen, ci.quantity
        FROM products p
            LEFT JOIN cart_items ci
                ON p.id = ci.product_id AND ci.user_id = '$user_id'
        ORDER BY p.name";

$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

// count number of products returned
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){


// INICIO DE CUADRICULA DE productos

echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-4 g-3">';

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);

echo '<div class="col">';
echo '<div class="card shadow-sm">';
echo "<div class='product-id' id='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
echo "<img src='{$imagen}' alt=''>";
echo '<div class="card-body">';
echo "<div class='product-name card-text' id='product-name'>{$name}</div>";
echo "<small class='text-muted'>$ ". number_format($price, 2, '.' , ',')."</small>";
echo '<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">';

echo '<div class="btn-group">';
//echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Añadir a Carrito</button>';
if(isset($quantity)){
echo "<input type='text' name='quantity' id='quantity' value='{$quantity}' disabled class='form-control' />";
echo "<button class='btn btn-success' disabled>";
echo "<i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>";
echo "</button>";
}else{
echo "<input type='number' name='quantity' id='quantity' value='1' class='form-control' />";
echo "<button class='btn btn-primary add-to-cart'>";
echo "<i class='fas fa-cart-plus'></i>";
echo "</button>";
}
echo "</div>";


echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';


  }

  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

// tell the user if there's no products in the database
else{
    echo "No hay productos encontrados.";
}
```

la apariencia visual logicamente cambia y se adapta a cualquier dispositivo pero he intentado modificar el codigo javascript al siguiente:

**Mi modificacion del codigo JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
var id = $(this).closest('div').find('.product-id').text();
var name = $(this).closest('div').find('#product-name').text();
var quantity = $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
window.location.href = "../agregar.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
});
```

pero no logra ejecutar la captura de los datos id, name ni quantity

Comment: Te recomiendo indentar correctamente tu código y cambiar todos esos `echo` por la [sintaxis de HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) para hacerlo más legible y fácil de analizar. Por cierto, los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), de lo contrario, se generan problemas como el que tienes ahora.

Comment: Ok tomare la sugerencia en consideracion.. pero en el caso de la ejecucion del JS es donde de momento requiero orientacion, ya que originalmente funciona perfecto porque es una estructura de tabla, y lo cambie a una estructura de galeria de imagen de boostrap y logicamente se me enredo el papagallo

Comment: Si el código HTML tiene errores como IDs repetidos, es muy probable que se complique hacer funcionar el Javascript. No puedes llegar a la meta si no arrancas desde la salida.

Comment: Eso lo comprendo, pero es que no tengo IDs repetidos en mi codigo..! de hecho lo he logrado solucionar comprendiendo el javascript que era donde tenia la confucion. Gracias tomare en cuenta la sugerencia de HEREDOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado con el siguiente codigo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.col').find('#product-id').text();
    var name = $(this).closest('.col').find('#product-name').text();
    var quantity = $(this).closest('.row').find('#quantity').val();
    window.location.href = "../agregar.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
    });
```

Resulta que la funcion `closest()` hace referencia al anterior selector puede hacerse referencia a una clase o a un tag y la funcion  `find()` debe tomar el valor puede ser de la clase `(.clase)` o del id `(#id)`.